# Clicking button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find a way to click this button using Selenium

```html
<button type="button" class="ArrowToggleButton_arrowButton__9RpIv StatsAdvancedFiltersPanel_safArrow__EqRgu" aria-expanded="false"><span class="ArrowToggleButton_arrowText__ep3Dn">Advanced Filters</span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="14" width="8" viewBox="0 0 8 14" data-no-icon="down" role="presentation"><polyline fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="6.5,1.6 1.5,7 6.5,12.4"></polyline></svg></button>
```

but it says it cannot find the element
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0scFD.png)

This is my code

```py
button_element = driver.find_element("name","ArrowToggleButton_arrowButton__9RpIv StatsAdvancedFiltersPanel_safArrow__EqRgu")
button_element.click()
print(button_element)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please remember to read [how to post a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding the argument list.
The  [Documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) should help you here.

In essence, you are matching a name, but check for the value of a className.
You're code would match something like this:
`<input name="ArrowToggleButton_arrowButton__9RpIv StatsAdvancedFiltersPanel_safArrow__EqRgu" />`

But you're trying to match for a class.

Your query should look something like this:

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ArrowToggleButton_arrowButton__9RpIv.StatsAdvancedFiltersPanel_safArrow__EqRgu")
```

As a hint: Matching against classes containing hashes (`9RpIv` in this case) is generally a bad idea, as they can change from release to release.
I would probably use an XPath expression to find the element for more stability.

Answer (score 0):

To click the "Advanced Filters" button using `xpath`, the selector is:

`"//button[contains(., 'Advanced Filters')]"`

Here's a full command to click it:

```py
button_element = driver.find_element("xpath", "//button[contains(., 'Advanced Filters')]")
button_element.click()
```